# How to use two merged pri lines

Tags: asterisk, voip

I have merged two PRI lines i.e now we have 60 channels on one span.Is there any extra configuration required for itOr we can continue with basic configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Just set same group for both pri with statment like

```
group=0
```

After that dial like

```
   exten =>_X,1,Dial(DAHDI/g0/${EXTEN},,r)
```

There are alot of examples available

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+ZAP+channels